# File not found - Google Safe Browsing Lookup API

Tags: api, safe-browsing

I try to make a browser call to

https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?

With and without the API key, etc, but each time and no matter what I do, I get:

```
File not found
Firefox can't find the file at https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?.
Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are using is AFAIk from the [Google Safebrowsing API V 1 which used to support `GET` requests and is now deprecated (and will be taken offline by December 1st)](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/developers_guide.html) - I **strongly recommend** switching to [V2 of the API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/developers_guide_v2.html) which from what I gather only supports requests via `POST`.

EDIT:

SORRY - I overread the "Lookup" part...

I just checked the URL you gave... From Firefox (latest version) I can confirm what you describe... OTOH when I try it via IE the result is different - it comes back with HTTP 403 which I assume is due to the fact that I don't have a valid key...

I can only conclude that Firefox does something Google won't accept - it can be related to User agent or whatever... have you tried this with a simple `wget` or some http client component/class ?

Comment: It's the lookup API that I am interested in - that doesn't have V1 and V2?

Comment: Thanks Yahia - I hope a solution can be found and it's not just an unnoticed Google error.

Comment: @AntonyCarthy I don't think it is an error - since Mozilla and Google have some special agreements I suspect that this API/URL behaves differently from Firefox than from IE...